# Order by min of two dates with nulls first for one column, ignore nulls for another

Tags: oracle

I want to order my data by the minimum date of two columns, with equal precedence. If Date1 has nulls, I want them to appear first. If Date2 has nulls, I just want to go by Date1. If both dates are null, it should appear at the top.

It 'should' never happen that Date1 is null and Date2 is not.

For example:

```
Date1      Date2
1/1/2012   1/1/2000
null       null
1/1/2009   1/1/2015
1/1/2013   null
1/1/2003   1/1/2003
```

Should end up as:

```
Date1      Date2
null       null
1/1/2012   1/1/2000
1/1/2003   1/1/2003
1/1/2009   1/1/2015
1/1/2013   null
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LEAST and COALESCE should give you what you're after:

```
with sample_data as (select to_date('01/01/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date1, to_date('01/01/2000', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date2 from dual union all
                     select null date1, null date2 from dual union all
                     select to_date('01/01/2009', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date1, to_date('01/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date2 from dual union all
                     select to_date('01/01/2013', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date1, null date2 from dual union all
                     select to_date('01/01/2003', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date1, to_date('01/01/2003', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date2 from dual)
select date1,
       date2
from   sample_data
order by least(date1, coalesce(date2, date1)) nulls first;

DATE1      DATE2     
---------- ----------

01/01/2012 01/01/2000
01/01/2003 01/01/2003
01/01/2009 01/01/2015
01/01/2013
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much.

Comment: it's worth noting that if there isn't a constraint in place to enforce the "date1 can't be null if date2 isn't null" then you should probably use the extra coalesce that @DavidAldridge's answer has. Or add in the constraint - something like: `alter table your_table add constraint your_table_chk check (case when date2 is not null and date1 is null then 1 else 0 end = 0);`

Answer (score 1):

I think you would want to:

```
order by least(coalesce(date1,date2),
               coalesce(date2,date1)) nulls first
```